# Is it worth to sort array before looking for element?

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting

We have array with 1000000 elements inside and we will need to find 100 times some value.
There are two options: first - sort it with heapsort and then search by binary search, second - sequential search.

Without calculations I would say that first option is better but...
In second option in worst case we have `num_of_elem * num_of_search = 100 * 1000000`, in first we have (heapsort is O(nlogn)) so `(1000000*log(1000000))*100*log(1000000) = 1000000*20*100*20`. That mean that second option is better 400 times.

Am I correct here?

Comment: `better 400 times.

Am I correct here?` You are forgetting about all the lower order terms and constant factors. Oh, and shouldn't that be 1000000a*20b+c __+__ (20d+e)*100 (sort once, search 100 times)? (While a "factor of 400" would be an indication that the lower number may way well stay lower, a factor of five in favour of thee more involved solution is in the range of *probably doesn't matter much*.)

Comment: [This talk](https://isocpp.org/blog/2019/06/allegro-means-both-fast-and-happy.-coincidence-andrei-alexandrescu) by Andrei Alexandrescu shows that it is generally hard to guess without measuring (because of architectural details of the hardware that are not considered during complexity analysis).

Comment: What about option 3: Hashing?

Comment: @SaiBot yep hashing is a good way and doable in `O(n)` or `O(n+m)` (depends on the circumstances) time and `O(m)` space where `n` is the array size and `m`  is the count of possible values used. there is no need to even sort and just single pass is needed ... so if `m` is small (like ASCII, or 8/16 bit int)  this is the best option. For arbitrary values is this a no go ...

Comment: @Spektre  Ah, I didn't even think about hashing... You should write an answer containing that. But why would the size of m matter in this case? Making a hash table doesn't take long if you have a good hash function, and space won't be an issue unless m is ridiculously large. Or at least so I thought.

Comment: @SecularisticSloth if the hash is small enough you do not need to binary search it but use it as direct index (similar to bucket sort) for such cases the result will have linear complexity `O(n)` or `O(n+m)`. If too big range (big `m`) then you need to hash or re-index the array and have ordered hash/index table which is accessed in `O(log(m))` resulting in `O(n.log(m))` complexity ... as the direct mapping would need a huge array instead.  SaiBot come up with hashing idea first ...

Comment: @Spektre (Ah, yes, sorry SaiBot) I don't see the reason for doing a binary search at all to be honest. Making a hash table over the big array (the items you want to search in) takes O(n) expected time, and then you can do each of the k lookups in O(1) expected time, for O(n + k) expected time total, right? (Edit: I just realised you use m to define the range of values, instead of number of searches... I didn't pay attention. Corrected it to k, which is the number of searches performed.)

Comment: @SecularisticSloth the bin search is hidden inside hasmap ... either it uses 1:1 mapping  table (without bin search) which need `2*m` space (can be huge imagine `m` for 32bit int ... that is 8 GByte ...) so if `m` is large bin search (index sort) is used on `m` instead to map value to index instead...

Comment: @Spektre I might just be misunderstanding what you are saying, but I think we might be talking about different things. The hash tables I've learned about uses neither direct addressing (1:1 mapping) or binary search. They use a hash function to compute the location of the element within a reasonably sized array. Given that the hash function is good and distributes elements evenly, inserts and lookups are expected to take `O(1)` time while a hash table over `n` element uses `O(n)` space.

Comment: Are the "elements" numeric?  What do you mean by "100 times some value" -- One element equals 100 times another element?  Some element is repeated 100 times?  Do you know _in advance_ how big the array is (at least approximately)?  (That would not apply to, say, an input stream.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that when the running time of an algorithm is specified using O-notation, it is 
'asymptotic'. Overly simplified, a running time of `O(log n)` means that your program performs `c*log n` steps, where c is some constant that you don't actually know. It could be quite large. Therefore, using real numbers in the formulas for running time will not give you accurate results.

Here are two approaches to find an answer to your question:

- you could run a bunch of tests, for different inputs, to compare the two methods. Choose whichever performs the best way for your application.
- You can do a slightly more in-depth theoretical analysis:

Let's say there are `n` elements in the array you want to search in,
   and you want to find `k` elements. So in your example, `n = 1000000`
   and `k = 100`.

If you sort and use binary search for each element,
   you use `O(n log n)` time for sorting and `O(k log n)` time for
   searching, for a total of `O(n log n + k log n)`. If you do linear
   search for each of the k elements, you use `O(kn)` time.

Now, if `k = O(log n)`, then `O(kn)` becomes `O(n log n)`, and using the two methods
   should be equally fast (asymptotically). However, if `k = Omega(log n)` (i.e, `k` is
   bounded from below by `log n`), then `n log n = O(kn)`, and sorting before searching is faster (asymptotically).

What this means is that you can use some test of the type `k < c log n` for some constant `c` and use the linear search method if the test succeeds and the sort+search method otherwise. The exact value of `c` would have to be defined using tests and benchmarks, again due to the running times being asymptotic.

**BONUS**

There is another fun algorithm you can use if you know all the `k` values beforehand. Let `A` be the `n` numbers you want to search in, and `B` be the `k` numbers you want to search for.

- Sort `B` (`O(k log k)` time )
- Iterate over `A`, and for each element `e`, do a binary search in `B` for `e` ( `O(n log k)` time in total)

This way you will determine which numbers in `B` are also in `A`, and it will take `O(n log k + k log k)`, which is asymptotically faster than (or as fast as) both the other methods if `k = O(n)` (for instance if `k < n`).

Comment: For your "bonus", iterating over A and looking for items in B is O(n log k), as you describe. But doing it the other way, iterating over B and looking for items in A might be faster. You want to iterate over the smaller set. That is `400*log(1000000)` is smaller than `1000000*log(400)`.

Comment: But, really, if you have two sorted arrays, you can find the intersection (which items are in both lists) in O(a+b), where a and b are the lengths of the respective lists, A and B. It's just a simple merge.

Comment: @JimMischel Appreciate the feedback! If the arrays were sorted initially, this would be true. But none of them are, so if you wanted to iterate over B and do binary search in A you would need to sort A first. That would result in `O(n log n)` for sorting and `O(k log n)` for searching. Assuming (as you do) that `k = O(n)`, isn't `O(n log k)` better?

Comment: I must have misunderstood. I thought you already had A sorted. Given that A is not sorted, you are correct.